# Accordion menu jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to achieve an accordion menu in jquery,

However it doesn't seem to work, and my submenu doesnt appear . ..

I've try various possibility by changing my jquery but nothing to do :(,

any help would be amazing !!

I attach my code below:

html:

```
 <div class="content-left">
    <ul id="accordion" class="level-1">

        <li><a href="#" class="ext1"><span class="icons1"><small>ELECTRICAL</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop1 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>


            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext2"><span class="icons2"><small>HOME & GARDEN</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop2 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext3"><span class="icons3"><small>PETS AND LIVESTOCK</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop3 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext4"><span class="icons4"><small>PROPERTY</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop4 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext5"><span class="icons5"><small>BUSINESS AND LOANS </small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop5 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>            </ul>
        </li>

       </div>
```

Jquery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    ( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#content-left ul#accordion.level-1').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('level-2')) {
            element.removeClass('level-2');
            element.find('li').removeClass('level-2');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('level-2');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('level-2');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('level-2');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
} )( jQuery );
    </script>
```

CSS:

```
 #accordion ul.level-2, #accordion ul.level-3 {
        display: none;
    }

    #accordion ul.active {
        display: block;
    }
```

OR the JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/8x7rjhz9/1/

Thank you for your time and advise in this !

---EDIT ---

How can i do it for three levels and let the stay active on click on an item list ?

3 LEVELS:

```
   <div class="content-left">
    <ul id="accordion" class="level-1">

        <li><a href="#" class="ext1"><span class="icons1"><small>ELECTRICAL</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop1 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<ul id="sub-menu" class="level-3 drop11">
    <li><a href="#">sub sub</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub sub</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub sub</a></li>
</ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>


            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext2"><span class="icons2"><small>HOME & GARDEN</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop2 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext3"><span class="icons3"><small>PETS AND LIVESTOCK</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop3 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext4"><span class="icons4"><small>PROPERTY</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop4 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext5"><span class="icons5"><small>BUSINESS AND LOANS </small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop5 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>            </ul>
        </li>

       </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('ul#accordion.level-1 li').on('click', function(){

        var element = $(this);
        if (element.hasClass('level-2')) {
            element.removeClass('level-2');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('level-2');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('level-2');
        }
    });
});
} )( jQuery );
```

NEW JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/430az1j4/5/

```
</script>
```

--- EDIT 3 PHP ----

I'm calling my third level category by php this way:

```
<?
$cats = array();

foreach (AdCategory::getList(array('filter' => array('parent_id' => null))) as $category){

    $subcats = AdCategory::getList(array('filter' => array('parent_id' => $category->id, 'ha' => 1)));

    if($category->exclude == 0){
        $cats[$category->name] = '';
        //$cats["main_path"] = $category->path_url_static;

        $this_cat = array_chunk($subcats, 10);

        foreach($this_cat as $chunk) {
            foreach($chunk as $subcat) { 

                if (strcmp($subcat->name , "Sub cat 1") == 0) {
                    $cats[$category->name] .= '<li><a href="'.$subcat->path_url.'">'.$subcat->name.'</a>';
                    $cats[$category->name] .= '<ul id="sub-menu" class="level-3 drop11">
                    <li><a href="/path">sub sub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/path">sub sub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/path">sub sub</a></li>
                    <li class="pad_last"><a href="/path">Other</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>'; 

                } else if (strcmp($subcat->name , "sub cat 2") == 0) {
                    $cats[$category->name] .= '<li><a href="'.$subcat->path_url.'">'.$subcat->name.'</a>';
                    $cats[$category->name] .= '<ul id="sub-menu" class="level-3 drop11">
                    <li><a href="/path">sub sub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/path">sub sub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/path">sub sub</a></li>
                    <li class="pad_last"><a href="path">Other</a></li></ul></li>';
                } 

                else {
                    $cats[$category->name] .= '<li><a href="'.$subcat->path_url.'">'.$subcat->name.'</a></li>'; 
                }

            }

        }
    }
    if (array_key_exists($category->name, $cats))
       $cats[$category->name] .= '<div class="clear"></div>';

}

?>
```

In fact - there are not in the html - it build this way for the two first level:

```
<div class="content-left">
    <ul id="accordion" class="level-1">

        <li><a href="#" class="ext1"><span class="icons1"><small>main 1</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop1 pt10">
                 <?=$cats['catname1']?>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext2"><span class="icons2"><small>main 2</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop2 pt10">
                <?=$cats['catname2']?>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext3"><span class="icons3"><small>main 3 </small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop3 pt10">
                <?=$cats['catname3']?>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/property" class="ext4"><span class="icons4"><small>main 4</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop4 pt10">
               <?=$cats['catname4']?>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By editing few lines in your script, the accordion effect can be achieved

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('ul#accordion.level-1 li').on('click', function(){

        var element = $(this);
        if (element.hasClass('level-2')) {
            element.removeClass('level-2');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('level-2');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('level-2');
        }
    });
});
} )( jQuery );
```

JS fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/430az1j4/4/

Comment: Thank you It works perfectly !!

Just a few question, I have edit my html,
If i want 3 levels for certain of the submenu - how can I achieve this ?

The last twice I would like to have is when i click to on elf the list item, I arrive to the new page, with the parent item open. Is tho s possible to achieve by any chance ?

Thank you for your time !!

Comment: Welcome and check out this js fiddle link which contains three levels  https://jsfiddle.net/vwnvqf0f/3/

Comment: Thank you, it works fine on the jsfiddle you give, unfortunalty it doenst work on my live website which content some php . . . ..  I have edit my questin with the way I call the third level by php and show how is working the html - slightly different from the example i've give - but with the same class> IF you have any idea how to make it work . .it would be amazing !! THank you for your time !!

PS: any idea about the active state to let it open ?

Comment: Could you elaborate this active state, like what should be the interaction and behavior

Comment: For example: If i click to one list subcategory from category 1: I would like the category 1 to stay open on the new page of the subcateogry I have just open. ( the new page who display all the content from the subcategory I have just clicked on) - let me know if the explanation is great or not :)

Comment: The explanation was great :) since we are dealing with two pages, will have to pass the category which is active from one page to another, for passing this category we can either use query params in the URL or session storage. Once the category is retrieved in the new page we can  open the appropriate category on page load

Comment: hmmm, ok. do you have any example of code by any chance ? and have any idea about the third level category through the php i have give ? Thank you really for your time !

Comment: No code examples for that :( and for the second question ensure that the html structure has a class called "submenu' in all parent li's.

Comment: Ok Ill try to achieve this :)

Regarding the third level, in your example, it use level-2 for class everywhere in the jquery, but the third level has level-3 and not level-2 as a class, I have add as a class submenu to the li parents. it worked for the two level this way but not the third one. SO in the jquery I ahve add everywhere where level-2  is call level-3 by 'level-2 level-3' instead of 'level-2'. But it doesnt work 100%, it display the third level - but bring to the page after 1 second  . . .any idea :( ?

Comment: class level-2 just hides the DOM, generically it is used to hide the children no matter what there level is. Regarding the other issue, compare the HTML from the live site with that of the jsfiddle html and ensure that they match.

Answer (score 1):

there are mainly two problems in your code

1) selector
2) haven't used preventDefault() function

I have updated the code check this

```
    <div class="content-left">
    <ul id="accordion" class="level-1">

        <li><a href="#" class="ext1"><span class="icons1"><small>ELECTRICAL</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop1 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>


            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext2"><span class="icons2"><small>HOME & GARDEN</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop2 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext3"><span class="icons3"><small>PETS AND LIVESTOCK</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop3 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext4"><span class="icons4"><small>PROPERTY</small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop4 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#" class="ext5"><span class="icons5"><small>BUSINESS AND LOANS </small></span></a>
            <ul id="sub-menu" class="level-2 drop5 pt10">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>            </ul>
        </li>

       </div>


( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#accordion.level-1 a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('level-2')) {
            element.removeClass('level-2');
            element.find('li').removeClass('level-2');
            element.find('ul').slideDown();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('level-2');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('level-2');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('level-2');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
} )( jQuery );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8x7rjhz9/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off utilising jQuery UI's accordion module:

Include the script tag to jQuery UI:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Use this format of HTML code:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Attach the script like so:

```
(function($) {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
})(jQuery);
```

See this page for more information:
https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

try following code or visit https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#accordion.level-1 li:has(.sub-menu) > a').on('click', function () {
        var $li = $(this).closest('li');
        if ($li.hasClass('active')) {
            $li.find('.sub-menu').stop().slideUp();
            $li.find('li.active').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $li.children('.sub-menu').stop().slideDown();
            $('#accordion li.active').removeClass('active').children('.sub-menu').stop().slideUp();
        }
        $li.toggleClass('active')
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jjgbx1p7/)

Also note that, since ID of an element must be unique I've changed `sub-menu` to a class.